# Cast from const char* to char* modifies data in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

In VC++, when I typecast the `const char*` value returned by `std::string::c_str()` to `char*` and print the casted value, nothing gets printed on the screen. Here is the code snippet

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string test() { return(string("HELLO"));}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  char* val;
  val = (char*) test().c_str();
  printf("\n %s\n", val);
  return 0;
}
```

When I simply check the ASCII value at `val[0]` it is 0. But under G++, the text `HELLO` gets displayed.

Is the cast from const char* to char* a non-standard one whose results are not defined?

Comment: The string returned from `cat` is destroyed at the end of the expression, leaving a dangling pointer, is it not? This is the same issue as a stringstream: `val = sstream.str().c_str();`

Comment: Awesome! I totally missed this point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cast is fine as long as you don't modify the value or read from it after altering the string (you should get *at least* a warning though).

The problem is that you call the function on a temporary (the temporary is the `string` returned by `cat()`). After the `;`, the temporary goes out of scope and `val` still points to memory managed by the temp. It's UB reading from it.

Comment: I wouldn't say just as long as you don't modify the value. Calling a non-const function on the string object would invalidate it as well, and though that's impossible here, it's important to know just how long you can use that pointer for. Just something I felt worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting undefined behavior, because the temporary returned by `test()` is immediately destroyed. The cast had nothing to do with it.

To eliminate the problem, assign the value returned by `test()` to a local variable. Now it will continue to exist up through the call to `printf`.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  string temp;
  char* val;
  temp = test();
  val = (char*) temp.c_str();
  printf("\n %s\n", val);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'd get similar behavior without the cast (changing the type of `val` to `char const*`):

```
char const* val;
val =  test().c_str();
printf("\n %s\n", val);
```

As mentioned in other answers the problem in this specific example is not the cast but the lifetime of the data pointed to by the pointer returned by `c_str()`.  That data is invalidated when the object it was obtained from dies (which in this case is at the semi-colon at the end of the line since it's a temporary object returned by the `test()` function).

Note that as chris points out in a comment, even if the pointer were obtained from a `c_str()` call on a longer-lived object, the data might become invalid for other reasons (basically if the string object was modified).